# Removed operator!= in C++20 standard library

Tags: c++, deprecated, std, comparison-operators, c++20

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), the `operator!=` of many standard library types, including [`std::unordered_map::operator!=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_cmp) and [`std::unordered_set::operator!=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/operator_cmp) is *removed* in C++20.

**What is the committee's rationale behind the decision?** Won't this make the comparison support asymmetric?